# Twisted HTTP Client access peer IP (server)

Tags: python, twisted

How can I access remote peer IP in this Twisted HTTP Client example? (From Twisted Docs)

Working with this example:

```
from sys import argv
from pprint import pformat

from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.web.client import Agent, readBody
from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers


def cbRequest(response):
    #print 'Response version:', response.version
    #print 'Response code:', response.code
    #print 'Response phrase:', response.phrase
    #print 'Response headers:'
    #print pformat(list(response.headers.getAllRawHeaders()))
    poweredby = response.headers.getRawHeaders("X-Powered-By")
    server = response.headers.getRawHeaders("Server")


    print poweredby
    print server

    d = readBody(response)
    d.addCallback(cbBody)
    return d

def cbBody(body):
    print 'Response body:'
    #print body

def main(reactor, url=b"http://www.example.com/"):
    agent = Agent(reactor)
    d = agent.request(
        'GET', url,
        Headers({'User-Agent': ['Twisted Web Client Example']}),
        None)
    d.addCallback(cbRequest)



    return d

react(main, argv[1:])
```

After searching on the Internet and SO, I found that it can be read from:

```
self.xmlstream.transport.getHandle().getpeername()
```

or

```
self.transport.getPeer()
```

However I don't know which Class "self" refers to and where to put it in the example code?

Any help? Tips? Ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: The remote server is surely "www.example.com" (which you could resolve to an IP address with a name resolver).  Can you explain what you're trying to do a little bit more?

Comment: Since connection has been already made, I can make it more efficient and skip the resolving of the hostname and just get the IP peer name. I want to crawl large amount of websites. Dont want to do it twice. I did it with urllib2 like this (peer = response.fp._sock.fp._sock.getpeername()), but dont know how to do it with twisted module

Comment: What do you plan to use the address for (this would be a good piece of information to include if you file a ticket)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to get the address, though you have to hack through some layers of abstraction and touch a private attribute:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

class ReadAddress(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.result = Deferred()

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.result.callback(self.transport._producer.getPeer())

def readAddress(response):
    p = ReadAddress()
    response.deliverBody(p)
    return p.result

@react
def main(reactor):
    a = Agent(reactor)
    d = a.request(b"GET", b"http://www.google.com/")
    d.addCallback(readAddress)
    d.addCallback(print)
    return d
```

Ideally, there would be a simpler (public!) interface to retrieve information like this.  It would be excellent if you could file a feature request in the Twisted tracker.

Comment: SUPER!!! Thank you!!! I am not that advanced in programming, so not sure if I can explain it well in feature request. I looked at https://twistedmatrix.com and https://github.com/twisted/twisted but don't see a way to open a ticket in the tracker. Do you know address where I can open it? If you wish, you can feel free to open it also.

Comment: Tickets are opened on twistedmatrix.com - after you use the login button (top right) to log in _with_ github. :)